# Slick Slider Carousel Counter not displaying first slide count, only starts once 2nd slide appears

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I have a slider with a counter that currently shows the full amount of slides but doesn't show the counter for the first slide. It wont activate until the 2nd slider appears. Once this has happened you can slide it back and it will show you the counter for the first slide.

I'm struggling to figure out how to show the first slide counter on first load,init.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrh9af7s/).

Code below:

```js
const addZeroPad = (val) => val.toString().padStart(2, "0");

    $('.gallery').each(function (index, sliderWrap) {

        const $module = $(this);
        const $slider = $module.find(".gallery__slides");
        const $slides = $slider.find(".gallery__item");
        const $numbersElem = $module.find(".gallery__counter");
        const $totalNumElem = $module.find(".gallery__counter .gallery__amount");
        const $activeNumElem = $module.find(".gallery__counter .gallery__count");

        

        if ($slides.length) {
            $slider.on("init", function(event, slick) {
                console.log(slick.$slides.length);
                $totalNumElem.text(addZeroPad(slick.$slides.length));
                $numbersElem.show();
              });

            $slider.on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
                $activeNumElem.text(addZeroPad(currentSlide + 1));
            });

            $slider.slick({
                dots: false,
                arrows: false,
                speed: 700,
                infinite: false,
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '1%',
                slidesToShow: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                draggable: true,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                variableWidth: false,
            });

        }
    });
```

```css
.gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.gallery__item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:0 20px;
}

.gallery__counter {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  font-size:50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family:arial;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>


<section class="gallery o-pd-top-md o-pd-btm-md" >
  <div class="gallery__slides js-fade-in o-delay-xs" data-type="gallery">
            
                <div class="gallery__item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956600684-97d3a4320e45?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
                </div>
              <div class="gallery__item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956600684-97d3a4320e45?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
                </div>
              <div class="gallery__item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956600684-97d3a4320e45?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
                </div>
              <div class="gallery__item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956600684-97d3a4320e45?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
                </div>
              <div class="gallery__item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956600684-97d3a4320e45?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
                </div>
              <div class="gallery__item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956600684-97d3a4320e45?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
                </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="container text-right">
    <div class="gallery__counter">
      <span class="gallery__count"></span>
      <span> - </span>
      <span class="gallery__amount"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Just add `$activeNumElem.text(addZeroPad(1));` in your `$slider.on("init"` callback ...?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!